# Icons for Scaffolding items not showing in the add menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

There are no icons in the add new scaffolding menu. I tried repairing VS 2022 but the issue is still the same.

Here is what it should be

[image: Normal Scaffolding Menu]

And here is what I have:

[image: My Scaffolding Menu]

Comment: Try deleting the `ImageLibrary.cache` file under `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ImageLibrary`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, tried it but still the same